# Javascript não carrega pre visualização de imagem

Tags: javascript, html

Estou utilizando o código abaixo para pré visualização de imagem antes do comando submit de um form html.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <img src="<?php echo $iniConf['LOGO']; ?>" class="img-responsive img-rounded" id="newLogo">
        <input class="hidden" id="searchNewLogo" name="logo" type="file" accept="image/*">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block" id="alterLogo">Alterar logo</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#alterLogo').click(function() {                
    $("#searchNewLogo").click();
});

$("#searchNewLogo").change(function() { 
    readNewImage(this);               
});               

function readNewImage(input) { 

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#newLogo').attr('src', e.target.result).hide().fadeIn();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);                    
    }
};
```

Ocorre um problema de não carregar a imagem quando os elementos html estão dentro do form. Se eu retirar o form a imagem é carregada corretamente.

Alguém poderia me explicar porque ocorre isso e como corrigir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sempre que você coloca um botão dentro de um formulário, o comportamento padrão dele é  enviar dados, ignorando qualquer instrução que seja posta após seu clique. Então você só precisa bloquear esse comportamento, assim:

```
$('#alterLogo').click(function(event) {                
    event.preventDefault();  //bloqueia o comportamento padrão do botão
    $("#searchNewLogo").click();
});
```

Comment: Carlos Fernando, realmente era isso mesmo! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Henqsan, de nada!